# Camera follow player issue (2d)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a 2D space game, similar to Roid Rage. I have a space shuttle in it. The shuttle will move around freely and will avoid obstacles. I have made the movement and rotation part of the shuttle successfully (using rigidbody2d). But now I am unable to make the camera follow the shuttle.
First I tried making the camera a child of shuttle. In this way, the camera followed the shuttle. But it didn't show any rotation of shuttle because I guess the camera also rotates with the shuttle in this case.
Then I did this:

```
public Transform shuttle;
private Vector3 offset;

void Start() {
    offset = transform.position;
}

void LateUpdate() {
    transform.position = shuttle.transform.position + offset;
}
```

In this case, the camera followed the shuttle but when I tap the screen and the shuttle is supposed to take a turn (in an orbit like path), it just rotates around its own axis.

Finally, I used this instead:

```
void LateUpdate() {
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, shuttle.position + offset, 0.125f);
}
```

Now, the result is that the shuttle is very shaky. Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution after searching on forums. Since I was using Rigidbody2D to move the shuttle, I had to turn on its Interpolate property from None to Interpolate. The shaking was fixed by this.

Answer (score 0):

Does something very simple like this not work? This is in the camera script, not attached to the GameObject.

```
public GameObject MyShuttle;

void LateUpdate() {
    this.transform.position = MyShuttle.transform.position;
}
```

Comment: I had already tried this. I found the solution and have posted an answer.